# AAB file is too larger than IPA file after production build in React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I have been working on React-Native for 3 months. All these days I was building the app only for android platform and the size of **AAB file** was **36.5 MB**, Today I built my app to iOS (IPA File). The size of **IPA file** is just **5.6 MB**.

> No code changes,
>   No new library installations,

#### But why both files have a huge difference in size?

Thank you!

Comment: do you add some third library for android alone? you can use the android studio apk analyze tool to explore it.

Comment: I just installed libraries for push notifications, and firebase. But not for android.. those supports both platfrom.. Anyways Let me check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

App bundles(AAB) cannot be installed as Android apps on user devices. Instead, they are meant to be used for generating APK files for specific device configurations. Different APK files are generated for different CPU architectures by the Play Store, the huge size difference may be because it contains information that is required to create APK for multiple device configurations. 
You  can use bundle tools to generate APKs locally https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool